# Babel ReactJS: Module build failed: SyntaxError Unexpected token SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, babeljs

I want to run a simple example of [pui-react-collapse](http://styleguide.pivotal.io/react_components_collapse.html) with *reactJS* to create a collapsed panels but it seems doesn't work.

Here my very simple code that i tried to execute:

```
import {Collapse} from 'pui-react-collapse';
class Test extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
<Collapse header="With Divider" divider>
                            <div> test</div>
                              </Collapse>
        )
    }
}
```

but I received a lot of errors, here a sample of the errors:

> ```
> WARNING in ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/svg-react-loader!./~/pui-css-iconography/svgs/spinner-sm.svg
> Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/wamp64/www/Myproject/node_modules/pui-css-iconography/svgs/spinner-sm.svg:
> Unexpected token (21:12)
>
>               19 |
>               20 |         return (
>             > 21 |             <svg {...this.props}>
>                  |             ^
> WARNING in ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/svg-react-loader!./~/pui-css-iconography/svgs/zoom_out.svg
> Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/wamp64/www/MyProject/node_modules/pui-css-iconography/svgs/zoom_out.svg:
> Unexpected token (21:12)
>
>       19 |
>       20 |         return (
>     > 21 |             <svg {...this.props}>
>          |             ^
>       22 |                   <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.5
>     7l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14zM7 9h5v1H7z"/>
>       23 |                 {React.Children.map(children, (c) => (c))}
>       24 |             </svg>
> ```

my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015-loose": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "d3": "^4.7.4",
    "d3-axis": "^1.0.6",
    "d3-brush": "^1.0.4",
    "d3-scale": "^1.0.5",
    "d3-time": "^1.0.6",
    "d3-time-format": "^2.0.5",
    "dc": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.7.1",
    "flux": "^3.1.2",
    "history": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "pui-react-collapse": "^7.5.1",
    "pui-react-panels": "^7.5.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.8",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.0.5",
    "react-d3-library": "^1.1.8",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.3",
    "react-faux-dom": "^3.0.1",
    "react-horizontal-timeline": "^1.1.1",
    "react-rangeslider": "^2.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-scrollbar-js": "^1.0.1",
    "react-time-slider": "0.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "svg-react": "^1.0.9",
    "svg-react-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

and my webpack.config.js

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: "./js/client.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loaders: ['babel',
                    {
                        loader: 'react-svg',
                        query: {
                            svgo: {
                                plugins: [{ removeTitle: false }],
                                floatPrecision: 2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src/",
        filename: "client.min.js"
    },
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
    ],
};
```

Do you have an idea about what I missed ?

Thanks in advance.